# Why was edit suggestion 22614668 rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22614668) on a question with the topic of class inheritance in JavaScript. The suggestion was rejected on a 2-1 decision with the following reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

I'm hoping someone could help explain in more specific terms what was wrong with the suggestion.

Answer (score 27):

You changed the OP's wording pointlessly. The OP used "base class", which you changed to "superclass". These are synonyms, and neither one is more correct than the other. So... why change it? Let the OP use the term they *choose to*. Especially since their actual code still says `BaseClass` and `ChildClass`.

You changed the OP's wording *incorrectly*. You changed "child class" to "superclass", which is the *opposite* of what the OP said and what their code does.

It was a bad edit, and one of those three reviewers wasn't paying enough attention.

---

> My suggested edit also rephrased the question, fixed typos, e.g., "&" vs "and", and added a tag.

Even ignoring the actual mistake your edit introduced, edits are meant to make the post a better version of itself. Fixing typos is fine. Adding appropriate tags is fine.

But "rephrasing" is only OK if it was objectively poorly phrased to begin with. Replacing one word with a word that means the exact same thing improves nothing. Replacing "&" with "and" rarely improves something. You don't get to put words in the OP's mouth; that's not what edits are for.

You make the post *better*, not more like how *you* would have said it.

Comment: My suggested edit also rephrased the question, fixed typos, e.g., "&" vs "and", and added a tag.

Regarding the change of words, I changed it to make as many improvements as I could while making an edit suggestion, and I made this specific change to mirror language specification terminology, e.g., `super` is a keyword in Javascript.

It's a fair point on the "child class" to "superclass" change. I didn't catch that, but wouldn't an edit by the reviewer be a better option than to reject the edit?

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund: "*My suggested edit also rephrased the question, fixed typos, e.g., & or "and", and added a tag.*" So? It's like saying that, hey I cleaned up your garage, so you shouldn't be upset that I drove my car through your wall. Your edit broke the post; that trumps any hypothetical good it may have done. And "rephrasing the question" is *not* what you should be doing. You should be making it a better form of itself, not restating it to be more like how you would have said it.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to assume bad faith. I rephrased the question for clarity, not for my own personal taste. You don't really address my other points: if what was damaging about the edit was a quick edit away, why not edit it, then approve it?

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund: "*I don't think there's any need to assume bad faith.*" I'm not assuming bad faith. I don't think you made a bad edit deliberately, but you did make a *bad edit*. And that's why it was rejected. As for "clarity" vs. "personal taste", what you call "clarity" very much *is* "personal taste". "Superclass" is not more or less clear than "base class", regardless of the `super` keyword in Javascript. They both mean the same thing, so it's not your place to decide which one gets used where. The same goes for "and" vs. "&"; stylistic choices are up to the OP.

Comment: "Clarify meaning without changing it" is mentioned second on the list of reasons to make an edit, so saying I have no place doing so based on the subjective nature of what constitutes "clear" seems to go against guidelines. Editing based on personal preference without consideration for adding substantial value to the community would be bad motivation for an edit.

Comment: "But 'rephrasing' is only OK if it was objectively poorly phrased to begin with." I think we're risking getting into a debate about what constitute objective vs. subjective opinion.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund: "*I think we're risking getting into a debate about what constitute objective vs. subjective opinion.*" Yes. That's why we err on the side of the OP's style and intent. You don't get to change "behavior" to "behaviour" just because you think its more "clear". If the OP wants it that way, and it is not *genuinely* a problem, then that's what they get. You make an edit to clarify meaning when the meaning is *unclear*, not when it is "not how I would have said it".

Comment: That's a strawman argument. I have reasonable motivation for everything I changed. Regarding terminology, as someone who's still learning new programming concepts, I can attest that consistency matters.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund: "*I have reasonable motivation for every edit I made.*" That doesn't make it right for you to make those edits, nor does it make it correct according to *our standards* for what constitutes a valid edit. "*Regarding terminology, as someone who's still learning new programming concepts, I can attest that consistency matters.*" And that's exactly why you should let the OP be consistent with what *they know*.

Comment: If the reason are meritorious, it should be. That's what it all depends on, isn't it? Comparing the changes to an edit with the sole purpose of changing AE to BE is disingenuous and precisely assumes bad faith.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund: "*If the reason are meritorious, it should be.*" Stack Overflow does not need arguments about trivial differences between "base class" and "superclass". We have no mechanism for allowing someone to put for such reasons, nor a forum in which a decision can be reached as to which is more "meritorious". As such, we give primacy to what the OP said.

Comment: That's another strawman. I'm not arguing for the establishment of a petty court on terminology; my edit suggestion consisted of numerous changes for reasons other than clarity and precision in terminology. It was my sincere belief that as a whole, they added some value to the community, not just me.

Comment: "And that's exactly why you should let the OP be consistent with what they know." Could you please elaborate on that? I'm saying that in the given context, "method" is more precise than "function”. If the change is more correct or valuable than what was said originally, surely that’s reason to make an edit suggestion, even if the original wasn’t outright wrong? That’s certainly the impression I have from reading the guidelines and meta questions, i.e., if it adds value, even if it’s minor, it’s a net positive and should be accepted.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund: "*If the change is more correct or valuable than what was said originally, surely that’s reason to make an edit suggestion, even if the original wasn’t outright wrong?*" No, it isn't. If "function" is a legitimate word in that point of usage, it is still legitimate even if "method" might be "more precise". Everyone understood the post before, so you haven't really fixed anything. All you're doing is creating more grunt-work for reviewers who have to sift through trivial changes to wording to satisfy someone's need to be "more precise".

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund: Focus on editing things that *matter*, not trivialities like that. That's all we're saying. It doesn't matter if you can present some argument that one world might be 0.01% better by some metric; it is not worth the time and effort to even have that discussion. And if you genuinely believe that turning "base class" into "superclass" matters... well, then you will likely find yourself alone on that one.

Comment: So is it fair to say you don't think the question wasn't sufficiently in need of improvement? I ask because another user has now edited the question, making largely similar changes, sans the error.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund: Largely similar? That doesn't accurately reflect your edit relative to theirs. Giant didn't change "base class" to "superclass", or replace "&" with "and". The closest to such a word-swap that he made was with "method" over "function". Equally importantly, his edit makes more significant changes than just some word swaps. It removes a superfluous sentence, for example. Overall, there is a lot more that's different between your changes than alike.

Comment: You're absolutely right, he went even further than I did in rephrasing the question. Isn't that precisely what you've been arguing was wrong about the edit suggestion, that it needlessly rephrased? If it's the change in relationship terminology that you disagree with, that's absolutely fine with me; that's feedback I can use in the future. Telling me that editing question without outright mistakes more significant than typos and that the asker's original phrasing trumps an attempt at improving clarity is against guidelines goes against everything I've read about editing questions.

Comment: See the [Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) for an example. On top of that come several meta questions and several prior edit suggestions which have largely been minor and approved. Also, the ampersand was changed in the edit.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund: "*You're absolutely right, he went even further than I did in rephrasing the question*" Please re-read the reason for your edit's rejection. His more substantial change *did* make the post easier to read. It removed sentences that don't matter, removed the "desperately" noise, and other things. Yours was ***just*** some typos and word swapping. "*Also, the ampersand was changed in the edit.*" No, the sentence that just so happened to contain the "&" was removed; it had nothing to do with the "&" itself.

Comment: The edit suggestion also changed the "desperately" phrasing. My question here is asking for clarification on the rejection reasoning. I rephrased the question conservatively to avoid a rejection based on deviation from original intent, which you've been arguing it did anyway, providing reason for the rejection. Now, you're arguing someone else did a good job at rephrasing it when they went even further. The broader authority on SO speaks in support of making edits even for minor reasons, such as the ones I suggested, in spite of what you're saying. Whose word should I abide by in the future?

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund: You seem to be trying to rules-lawyer your way around a very simple concept: your edits need to actually improve the post in the eyes of people *who are not you*. Your edit was rejected because, in the eyes of people who are not you, it did not. You don't have to agree with it; that's the way it is. There's no arguing around it, no dodging it. I have provided reasoning; you can either accept it or reject it, but *that is the reason why*.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund: Stop trying to use the letter of what people are saying against the *spirit* of what people are saying. Your edit was bad because it was trivial and pointless (when it wasn't erroneous). Tiny Giant's edit, ***on the whole*** was far more significant. It doesn't matter if one small part of Tiny Giant's edit was similar to yours; that doesn't make your edits *as a whole* the same. Again, don't rules-lawyer this; take the information and learn from it.

Comment: That was established by the time I posted the question. If you can't answer the question, that's fair. You're contradicting yourself when you're first telling me the question needed no improvement, then that it needed greater improvement of the same kind I suggested. Characterizing my referencing the guidelines as legalistic and suggesting I'm recalcitrant when pressed on said disparity is just astonishing.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund: I never said it needed *no* improvement. And no, Tiny Giant's post is not "of the same kind I suggested". The problem here is that you're interpreting everything being said through the lens of "I have been wronged." You see *one thing* of TG's post that looks kind of like yours (and it isn't even like yours, because he removed the word entirely; you just changed its form) and thus, his edit is of the "same kind" as yours. I characterize your argument as legalistic because that's what you're doing: nitpicking every single word choice to make it paint you in the best light.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund there is a different bar for reviews that require editing (like yours) and that don't (like Giant's) - both required to make question better, but one without reviews can make non-substantial changes (like single tag or spelling mistake). You are welcome to research that subject and propose "feature-request" if you disagree.